# How to deal with keyword arguments that happen to be keywords in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, keyword, keyword-argument

Given the following method which takes two keyword arguments `begin` and `end`:

```
def make_range(begin: 0, end: -1)
  # ...
end
```

I can *call* this method without problem:

```
make_range(begin: 2, end: 4)
```

But how do I use the keyword arguments when *implementing* the method, given that both happen to be Ruby [keywords](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/keywords_rdoc.html)?

This obviously doesn't work:

```
def make_range(begin: 0, end: -1)
  begin..end
end
```

Note that this is just an example, the problem applies to all keywords, not just `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Alternatively, use *kwargs* and `kwargs[:begin]`/`kwargs[:end]`. You will have to make old school checks for argument correctness and default values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Easy solution

Please find other variable names. (e.g. [`min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-min) and [`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-max) or `range_begin` and `range_end`)

## Convoluted solutions

#### local_variable_get

You can use [`binding.local_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) :

```
def make_range(begin: 0, end: 10)
  (binding.local_variable_get(:begin)..binding.local_variable_get(:end))
end

p make_range(begin: 10, end: 20)
#=> 10..20
```

#### Keyword arguments / Hash parameter

You can also use [keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html).

```
def make_range(**params)
  (params.fetch(:begin, 0)..params.fetch(:end, 10))
end

p make_range
#=> 0..10
p make_range(begin: 5)
#=> 5..10
p make_range(end: 5)
#=> 0..5
p make_range(begin: 10, end: 20)
#=> 10..20
```

Comment: That should be `params.fetch(:begin, 0)` and you could use `**params` instead of `params = {}`.

Comment: Why do you even ask if you know the answer ? :)